# How to Join tables and show even if there are no rows in table 2

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have 2 tables, 1 with users and another with transactions. I am trying to display all users with the sum of their transactions.

The statement below is showing correctly except it will only include users that have transactions. How can I list all users, and if there is no transaction it should display sum as 0?

Here is the statement I am using:

```
SELECT 
    user.ID, user.FirstName, user.LastName, 
    user.Username, 
    SUM(transaction.Amount) As Total
FROM    user 
    LEFT JOIN transaction 
        ON user.ID = transaction.runnerID
WHERE user.event = 'EventX' 
    AND user.Active = 'True' 
    AND (user.tran_result = '1' OR user.tran_result ='manual' )  
    AND transaction.event = 'EventX' 
    AND (transaction.tran_result = '1' OR transaction.tran_result ='manual' )
GROUP BY user.ID
ORDER BY user.LastName ASC
```

I assume it is the WHERE statement that is removing those rows, but if I remove the WHERE statement and place those details as part of the LEFT JOIN it seems to just hang trying to get results. (There are about 2,000 users and 40,000 transactions)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the criteria for the transaction table into the JOIN condition. Putting it into the WHERE clause effectively turns your outer join into an inner join:

```
SELECT ....
FROM user
LEFT JOIN transaction 
    ON user.ID = transaction.runnerID 
       AND transaction.event = 'EventX' 
       AND (transaction.tran_result = '1' OR transaction.tran_result ='manual' )
WHERE user.event = 'EventX' 
  AND user.Active = 'True' 
  AND (user.tran_result = '1' OR  user.tran_result ='manual' )
GROUP BY user.ID
ORDER BY user.LastName ASC
```

Comment: and you can shorten the ON condition to `AND transaction.tran_result IN('1', 'manual')` and also the last WHERE condition to: `AND user.tran_result IN('1', 'manual')`

Comment: I tried doing it your way, but then the query just seems to hang without returning any results.

Comment: An index on `transaction.runnerID` could probably improve the performance. And maybe one on `transaction.tran_result` (but that depends on the distribution of the data)

Comment: I indexed runnerID and shortened the ON but it still hangs if I move it within the JOIN. Here is what I have now.

    `SELECT ... , SUM(COALESCE(transaction.Amount)) As Total
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN transaction ON user.ID = transaction.runnerID
AND transaction.event = 'EventX' AND transaction.tran_result IN('1','ticker','bill','manual')
WHERE user.event = 'EventX' AND user.Active = 'True' AND user.tran_result IN('1','bill')  
GROUP BY user.ID
ORDER BY user.LastName ASC`

Comment: What does the execution plan say?

Answer (score 0):

[Left Outer Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join)

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is different than `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: No, left join is the same as the left outer join.  The outer keyword is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `SUM(transaction.Amount)` to `SUM(ISNULL(transaction.Amount, 0))`?  This will ensure that a NULL value (i.e. no matching transactions) is treated as 0.